# Can`t Create Gtk 2.0 Project in Mono - An error has occurred File Widget could not be written-

Tags: mono, gtk

If I create a new Gtk 2.0 Project in Mono(Linux) I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred
File Widget could not be written.
System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
```